# Inter-microservices client communication issue with Keycloak - Jhipster

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, microservices, jhipster, keycloak

I created one gateway application using JHipster without service discovery, with keycloak oAuth2 server. Then another microservice (core) using JHipster.

I configured Zuul to forward requests to microservices using static URL that will be managed after that by Infrastructure:

`zuul:
  routes:
    core:
      path: /core/**
      url: http://localhost:7071/core`

Wen calling a webservice from Front-end to microservice or gateway everything goes well, the issue that we have is when "core" microservice tries to call a web service in gateway, gateway is returning 200 with login page in body content:

In "core" microservice, we configured FeignClient:

> @FeignClient(name="gateway", url="localhost:8080/", configuration = FeignConfiguration.class)
>   public interface UsersResourceControllerApiClient extends UsersResourceControllerApi {
>   }

```
public interface UsersResourceControllerApi {

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/getCustomerIdOfCurrentUser",
    produces = "*/*", 
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<UUID> getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET();
```

}

```
security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            client-id: internal
            client-secret: internal
        resource:
            user-info-uri: http://xx/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

in gateway side:

```
security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            access-token-uri: http://xx/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/token
            user-authorization-uri: http://xx/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            client-id: web_app
            client-secret: web_app
            scope: openid profile email
        resource:
            user-info-uri: http://xx/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

The authorisation bearer is passed in the header of request from core to gateway:

> 2018-10-17 12:01:12.130 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] ---> GET http://localhost:8080/api/getCustomerIdOfCurrentUser HTTP/1.1
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.130 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] Accept: */*
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.131 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] **Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJhZDVVUWNuNFROMjdmakVoSk5nSEs4TDB5M19wdXNKaGowV09TY0xEVUxrIn0.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.VJNT61lZr0LvYB2SewGBk025q4TC7ArX7omw4e4kH3wDg76R6_okLj45RO136tZyCz3INnQa5Al73ft7eUM8ccIlOowUV4OLEvIrWSXMyAocxMz36gVGUz6p08ly1aaJX9-JgKDHgFVO-AhHw_MBF-H3vbpaOhTYvTTd8LRsJYj8YFmbfvhCt4GREhoolo6RhlO_J_dt3vV7G4u-OWkW7UTBVCP9rVWhbih2svhrMXbrOp5wMnnWT1OhPS2yJwOjZ2QR8JwOhd-uvtNOEdejkqkAV6PBB4GvK-1bcBTi4nExERpF0QpHd9IrqqnB8dytPNA-dmp2xh6Y0-RI_xu0Ww**
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.142 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] ---> END HTTP (0-byte body)
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.507 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] <--- **HTTP/1.1 200 OK (357ms)**
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.508 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] cache-control: no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.508 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] connection: keep-alive
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.508 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] content-length: 3579
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.510 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] content-security-policy: frame-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.510 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.510 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] date: Wed, 17 Oct 2018 11:01:12 GMT
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.510 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] server: WildFly/11
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.512 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] set-cookie: KC_RESTART=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCIgOiAiNjU2MTFmMWQtMGU5Yy00MzZiLWI2YzctNTgzMzFmNGYyMDI5In0.eyJjaWQiOiJ3ZWJfYXBwIiwicHR5Ijoib3BlbmlkLWNvbm5lY3QiLCJydXJpIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL2xvZ2luIiwiYWN0IjoiQVVUSEVOVElDQVRFIiwibm90ZXMiOnsic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQgcHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly84Ny4xMDEuMjUxLjE5MDoxODUwNy9hdXRoL3JlYWxtcy9qaGlwc3RlciIsInJlc3BvbnNlX3R5cGUiOiJjb2RlIiwiY29kZV9jaGFsbGVuZ2VfbWV0aG9kIjoicGxhaW4iLCJyZWRpcmVjdF91cmkiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwODAvbG9naW4iLCJzdGF0ZSI6IlNmNW9ZaSJ9fQ.V-tQ2vO9P0iOlD6iEwKFoCKHOcmvmCeUr-iXkUStTb8; Version=1; Path=/auth/realms/jhipster; HttpOnly
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.513 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] set-cookie: AUTH_SESSION_ID=bde7090a-6f18-4da0-be3d-c6a19502101e.5547e156b5e8; Version=1; Path=/auth/realms/jhipster; HttpOnly
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.513 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] x-content-type-options: nosniff
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.513 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.515 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] x-powered-by: Undertow/1
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.515 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] x-robots-tag: none
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.515 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.515 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] 
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.516 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET]
>
> ```
>         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
> <title>        **Log in to jhipster**
> ```
>
> ***
>
> 2018-10-17 12:01:12.516 DEBUG 20704 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] m.c.p.a.UsersResourceControllerApiClient : [UsersResourceControllerApiClient#getCustomerIdOfCurrentUserUsingGET] <--- END HTTP (3579-byte body)

From gateway side, it's considered as anonymous session below logs:

> Enter: com.example.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=2018-10-17T11:01:12.222Z, **principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE**, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.251 DEBUG 4848 --- [ XNIO-2 task-15] c.m.motorna.aop.logging.LoggingAspect    : Exit: com.example.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
>   2018-10-17 12:01:12.312  INFO 4848 --- [ XNIO-2 task-15] Spring Security Debugger                 :
>
> ---
>
> New HTTP session created: puar4BUKwsI4c8Y6HeLGW4yw8pJD8x3dgkgQweRc
>
> Call stack:

```
at org.springframework.security.web.debug.Logger.info(Logger.java:44)
at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugRequestWrapper.getSession(DebugFilter.java:166)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:279)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:279)
```

> ---
>
> 2018-10-17 12:01:12.315  INFO 4848 --- [ XNIO-2 task-20] Spring Security Debugger                 :
>
> ---
>
> Request received for GET '/login':
>   HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /login ]
>
> servletPath:/login
>   pathInfo:null
>   headers: 
>   Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJhZDVVUWNuNFROMjdmakVoSk5nSEs4TDB5M19wdXNKaGowV09TY0xEVUxrIn0.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.VJNT61lZr0LvYB2SewGBk025q4TC7ArX7omw4e4kH3wDg76R6_okLj45RO136tZyCz3INnQa5Al73ft7eUM8ccIlOowUV4OLEvIrWSXMyAocxMz36gVGUz6p08ly1aaJX9-JgKDHgFVO-AhHw_MBF-H3vbpaOhTYvTTd8LRsJYj8YFmbfvhCt4GREhoolo6RhlO_J_dt3vV7G4u-OWkW7UTBVCP9rVWhbih2svhrMXbrOp5wMnnWT1OhPS2yJwOjZ2QR8JwOhd-uvtNOEdejkqkAV6PBB4GvK-1bcBTi4nExERpF0QpHd9IrqqnB8dytPNA-dmp2xh6Y0-RI_xu0Ww
>   Accept: */*
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_144
>   Host: localhost:8080

```
 Security filter chain: [
   WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
   SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
   HeaderWriterFilter
   CorsFilter
   CsrfFilter
   LogoutFilter
   OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter
   RequestCacheAwareFilter
   SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
   AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
   SessionManagementFilter
   ExceptionTranslationFilter
   FilterSecurityInterceptor
 ]
```

Looking for your support :)

Comment: @jhipster team, any support? did you face this issue?